# Declaring an uninitialized variable without a null constructor

Tags: c++

Consider the `DUPoint` class, whose declaration appears below. Assume this code appears in a file named DUPoint.h:

```
#include <string>  
class DUPoint {  
public:  

  DUPoint (int x, int y);  

  int getX () const;  
  int getY () const;  

  void setX (int x);  
  void setY (int y);  

  void print();  

private:  
  int x_;  
  int y_;  
};
```

Is it true that you cannot declare an uninitialized `DUPoint` variable with a statement such as `DUPoint P;` using this class as currently configured because it has no null constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if there is a user-declared constructor, no default constructor will be generated implicitly by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a constructor, then the default one won't be generated. Of course, adding one is just a matter of

```
DUPoint();
```